# Zend Framework application displays "Application Error" when I click Register button. My code below

Tags: php, zend-framework

My zend framework app:

```
 ***my application.ini***
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = my user account
resources.db.params.password = my password
resources.db.params.dbname = my database
```

---

```
public function addAction()
{
    // action body
    $form = new Application_Form_Album();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Register');
    $this->view->form = $form;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
    {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) 
        {
            $name = $form->getValue('name');
            $email = $form->getValue('email');
            $username = $form->getValue('usename');
            $password = $form->getValue('password');
            $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
            $albums->addUser($name, $email, $username, $password);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            //echo "data inserted!";
        }
```

enter code here

```
 ***My Model***
public function addUser($name, $email, $username, $password)
{
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,);
    $this->insert($data);
}
```

There seems to be a problem in this line  `$albums->addUser($name, $email, $username, $password);` because in this line the script stops and display "application error.

Please help me on this. 
My database is ok.
Database config seems ok. 
I think the model is fine. And the controller is okay. 
Please help me where am I wrong at?

When I open the form for this, it displays. But when submit the data browser displays "error occured Application Error"

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the application error?

Comment: Make sure you're in development mode so you can see error messages and exceptions